# R: KNN (knn3Train/caret) extract probabilities?

Tags: r, r-caret, knn

In R, `knn3Train` via `caret` package allows you to view the probability likelihood of each class. How do you extract the probabilities? The data does not read as a table.

```
foo<-knn3Train(train, test, class, k = 5, prob = TRUE)
foo<-pred
pred
# [1] "1" "1" "1"

attr(,"prob")
#        0   1
# [1,] 0.2 0.8
# [2,] 0.0 1.0
# [3,] 0.2 0.8
```

Comment: Post a complete code snippet with your question

Answer (score 0):

Alex is right! It seems so simple but as a newbie in R documentation can be hard to understand. THANK YOU!

```
attr(foo, "prob")
```